# Are your submissions to the writer's guild protected from unwanted readers?

Tags: copyright

Can people read your submission when you use the [registration system](https://www.wgawregistry.org/) for registering scripts? I am wondering if people can read your submissions within the writer's guild, or if the documents are sealed and protected and your writing can be kept safe until you need it in court for evidence. Can they still be read by employees within the guild or is there some technology that also prevents that from ever happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is answered by their section [Registration Details: Access to copies of Deposited Work](https://www.wgawregistry.org/regdetails.aspx):

> Because the deposited material cannot be returned to the writer without defeating the purpose of registration, registered material may not be withdrawn. It is therefore important to always retain a separate copy of the material being registered.
>
> If a writer finds it necessary to obtain a copy of deposited material, duplicates may be purchased for the price of registration upon written request by one or more of the listed authors, identified by photo ID. In the event an author is deceased, proof of death and consent of the representative of the heirs and/or estate must be presented in order to obtain a copy of the material.
>
> […] In no event, except under these provisions, shall any deposited material, copies of deposited material, or information regarding deposited material be provided unless an official guild action, court order, or other legal process has been served.

To summarize:

- Not even the author can casually browse their own submitted files.
- The fact that copies can be obtained by presenting paperwork (without some type of password) means the content can be accessed by some employees in plain text.